# How to get portal preferences setting on Liferay

Tags: java, settings, preferences, liferay-6, portal

I am a Liferay user, I need to get some of properties in my liferay portal, such as : Name, Virtual Host, Mail Domain, etc...(control panel/portal setting), in my code, is there any api to do this ?
(control panel/portal setting)

I had tried with PortalPreferences, but still dont know how to get it at all.

Please help!.

Thanks advance.

(Liferay portal 6.0.6)

Answer (score 0):

These details are stored in different tables.

Name you can get from Account object, get it using AccountLocalServiceUtil method

```
getAccount(long companyId, long accountId)
```

Get accountId from company object.

VirtualHostName you can get from VirtualHostLocalServiceUtil method

```
fetchVirtualHost(long companyId, long layoutSetId)
```

set layoutSetId value as 0.

MailDomain you can get from company object `company.getMx()`

Some information are stored in preferences , you can get it from PropsUtil.get(KEY).

Regards,

Regards,